# PHP cli uses different php.ini file when run by cron

Tags: debian, php.ini, cakephp, php-cli

My CakePHP console script is having problems executing under cron. It complains about missing Mysql connections and such.

After a little investigating I found that php run by cron uses a different php.ini file compared to when I run it in the terminal.

What's even more strange is that in the terminal, php does not use the cli config:

**PHP run in the terminal:**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

**PHP run by cron:**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xcache.ini
```

I have no idea why it's not using the same config files. I don't notice anything special in the `ENV` variables in the terminal or when run as cron.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is standard behavior or not, but you can always add

`-c /usr/local/lib/php.ini`  to the command to use a custom config.

Answer (score 3):

You are maybe not using the same `php` binary in the terminal and in cron, because of a different `PATH` setting.

Enter `which php` in the terminal and put the full path to the `php` binary in your cron script.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Oliver - you have to put the full path to php in cron. You can also include a PATH parameter in the cron file as well but probably best to to an absolute path to php.